# How to make this object wobble with animation gradually getting slower

Tags: animation, graph-editor, timeline

I'm trying to do an animation of an object, which is struck by a hammer (as reference). When the object is struck I have made some keyframes of the movement (Rotation & Location), and distributed the keyframes a little bit random to get a more natural motion. But the animation in between the frames looks unnatural end stops very sudden, without slowing down gradually towards the end of the animation.

In the end keyframe I have also selected for it to be ease out, but it doesn't make a difference.

I have attached my Blender file, and also found a reference of a cymbal which is struck, and slows down.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/paTNK8PTye4

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one possibility is to delete all keyframes between the first and the last, then select all keyframes -> T -> elastic

result:

[image]

after that you could sample keyframes to do your fine tuning.

Comment: Thank you Chris!